# Puppeteer Sharp error on second download to PDF on ASP MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, puppeteer-sharp

I'm implementing the following code to use Puppeteer Sharp for generating PDF on an ASP MVC 5 application, on the first request it works fine, but on any following request it takes too long to load any url and crashes, I tried disabling the headless and get the same result, I created this as an extension method for the controller

```
using PuppeteerSharp;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class MvcPdfExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<ActionResult> ViewAsPdf(this Controller controller,
            string fileName,
            string actionName,
            string controllerName,
            object routeValues = null)
        {
            var HostPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/");
            var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher(new BrowserFetcherOptions()
            {
                Path = HostPath
            });
            var revisionInfo = await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);
            var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
            {
                Headless = false,
                ExecutablePath = revisionInfo.ExecutablePath,
            });
            var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
            var cookies = controller.Request.Cookies.AllKeys;
            foreach (var cookieKey in cookies)
            {
                var cookie = controller.Request.Cookies[cookieKey];
                await page.SetCookieAsync(new CookieParam
                {
                    Name = cookie.Name,
                    Value = cookie.Value,
                    Domain = controller.Request.Url.Authority
                });
            }
            try
            {
                var url = controller.Url.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, "http");
                var waitOptions = new WaitUntilNavigation[]
                {
                WaitUntilNavigation.Load
                };
                await page.GoToAsync(url, null, waitOptions);
                var pdfOptions = new PdfOptions
                {
                    PrintBackground = true
                };
                var file = await page.PdfDataAsync(pdfOptions);
               
                return new FileContentResult(file, "application/pdf")
                {
                    FileDownloadName = fileName
                };
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new ContentResult {
                    Content = $"Error generando PDF: Tipo: {e.Source} Mensaje: {e.Message}"
                };
            }
            finally {
                await page.DisposeAsync();
                await browser.CloseAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```